# php_flag set in virtual host ignored

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

I need to have enable_post_data_reading set to off for a specific set of paths on a site, and am having trouble getting it to work. Situation is as follows:

Apache 2.2.22, PHP 5.4.34

Attempting to use  in  directive to set the flag.

URL rewriting is used (it's a Drupal site), so per-directory htaccess files won't work.

If I set enable_post_data_reading to "off" in php.ini, the post data is treated as expected, and the specific pages work, but it breaks the rest of the site. However, I at least proved to myself that the setting works at all.

If I set a test environment variable inside the  directive, it is visible on the expected pages, so the  is matching correctly.

However, if I set enable_post_data_reading to "off" inside the  directive, it is ignored.

Similarly, if I set it to "on" in php.ini, then set it to "off" in the virtual host, it stays on.

It would appear that although this construction works fine:

```
<VirtualHost 192.169.0.1:80>
   # Virtual host name, docroot, etc.

   <Location /apply/>
      SetEnv foo bar
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

...if I do this:

```
<VirtualHost 192.169.0.1:80>
   # Virtual host name, docroot, etc.

   <Location /apply/>
      php_flag enable_post_data_reading on
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

the php_flag instruction is ignored.

So, what am I doing wrong? Is there some other place I could set the flag that would work?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so we did a substantial amount of testing. It appears that the Location directive doesn't work properly when the URL has been rewritten, so that the PHP flag is not set.

We have however discovered a work-around:

- Set the Virtual Host's Location directive to trigger on a file (eg. /apply.php) instead of the path.
- Create a symlink in the top web directory to index.php, with whatever name you used for the Location.
- Add a new rewriteRule to the .htaccess file, before the standard Drupal rules that redirect everything to index.php, so that everything with the paths you need to be affected by the PHP flag are rewritten to the symlink instead.

This seems to be working exactly as we need it to: the PHP flag is set, and Drupal handles the request as normal. Rather indirect, but it's better than any of the other possible solutions.